# How do I add a global library to the Android Studio(0.8.14 or above)?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

How do I add a global library to the Android Studio(0.8.14 or above)?

Such as: android_sdk\platforms\android-XX\data\layoutlib.jar

In eclipse ,I can add it via "User Library"

BTW,how about Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

I think the equivalent within Android Studio would be to create a separate module within your project and select the "Import JAR or AAR" option. You could then include the module within your other modules using something like:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':mylibrary')
}
```